# adding fadeTo Method in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add fadeTo to this code snippet. When `this` adds the class `current` i want it to fade in. But I don't know how to solve, and where I've have to put the `fadeTo();` parameter.

```
$(this).bind("click", function() {
            navClicks++;
            $(this).addClass('current').parents('ul').find('a').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
            offset = - (panelWidth*z);
            alterPanelHeight(z);
            currentPanel = z + 1;
            $('.panel-container', slider).animate({ marginLeft: offset }, settings.slideEaseDuration, settings.slideEaseFunction);
            if (!settings.crossLinking) { return false }; // Don't change the URL hash unless cross-linking is specified
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure which DOM element you're looking to `fadeTo()`, but take a look at this jsfiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/37XEp/1/

Answer (score 0):

i have a class "current" which i add on click. in your example the "click me" and i want to fade in the green color of your "Click me" text slowly... nevermind the pikachu!